# Tips to sync up webapps and svn?

Tags: svn, web-applications

I would love to get some tips from other people that have had this problem. I'm doing front-end development on java-based apps.

I have my source in one diretory, /usr/src. My projects build and deploy to Tomcat in /usr/tomcat/webapps. Since the work I'm doing is all front-end, I have to edit the deployed files in /usr/tomcat/webapps so that I can see my changes immediately.

I would absolutely LOVE to have a system that will automatically sync my changes to a particular file(css, js, or jsp for example) back to the same file source control.

I've been thinking along the lines of creating a background process that does a 1-1 mapping of files, but this will quickly become cumbersome.

Does anyone have an existing system they use, or some recommendations on what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your system so that your web server serves files directly from your svn working tree.  Perhaps a symbolic link from /usr/tomcat/webapps/some-static-directory to the appropriate place in your svn tree?

Answer (score 0):

I've added application's exploaded directory to the project in IDE (Idea). When I need to try something "on the hot" - simply make changes in exploaded files. When I have a good result - simply copy changes to the working copy of source.

Probably it isn't the best solution but work for me. The only thing - it is not convinient when I need to change many files. But almost all work could be splited to small portions.